# Test suite failed to run TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to start using jest in my React App but getting this error:

Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

  at node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:40:27
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:1018:5)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-test-renderer/shallow.js:6:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:11:39)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total

This is what I have installed:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
```

This my starter code just to start testing:

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';



Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });

test('should render without error', () => {});
```

I guess that problem is with Dependencies but not sure how I can fix it.
If you say to remove Jest as it is coming with react, I get the same error even if I remove Jest

This is my test script:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test",
  }
```

Comment: So what is throwing the error? There is likely a stacktrace included with the error output, can you include that in your question? (*Plain formatted text, please*).

Comment: Sorry I tried to include as a plain text but it does not seem to work. I also included stacktrace

Comment: Is that your full & complete test code? The error seems to imply you are shallowly mounting a component for test but your `test` is empty, nothing is mounted.

Comment: I've know that test is empty and it suppose to pass even if test is empty. I just realised that my react version is 15.6.2 with react-dom version 15.6.2 Which is probably causing this error. I found it here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14763

Comment: Ah, does updating to react v16.x resolve issue for you?

Comment: I will try first uninstalling enzyme adapter16 and if that doesn't work I will try to reinstalling it and updating React to version 16 and hopefully it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224308/discussion-between-darkseid-and-drew-reese).

Comment: So after uninstalling Jest(knowing that React has build in Jest) and uninstalling Enzyme-adapter-16 everything starts working, in the end I think I need to install Enzyme-adapter-16 back with updated React and React-Dom versions which have to be equal

Answer (score 0):

Updating React and React-dom to the newest version solves problem as I am using

```
enzyme-adapter-react-16
```

I have to use React and React-dom versions greater than 16. My version was 15.7
Here is the command for updating:

```
npm install --save react@^17.0.1 react-dom@^17.0.1
```